# Interact with screenshot and xml in AppiumInspector, TestSigma and other testing platform

Tags: android, reactjs, xml, android-emulator, appium

I am working on app where one of my use case is to click an element by locating it on screenshot and get its corresponding xml data.
Actually I have xml and screenshot of the app that is running on emulator and that xml has certain data like xpath of that element, bounds or coordinates of that element, etc.

How these interactable screenshots are made, I need a way to make this.

Thank you

I am figuring out how we can implement this in ReactJS app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.